# Provisioning profile "com.myCompany.myApp" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.authentication-services.autofill-credential-provider entitlement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, ios12, code-signing-certificate

So I'm trying to add AutoFill Credential Provider to my app but I keep on having signing errors. The steps I followed are:

1. Adding a new AutoFill Credential Provider target
2. Creating a provisioning profile for that target
3. In, the new created target > Info.plist > `NSExtension`, adding `NSExtensionAttributes` (dictionary) > `ASCredentialProviderExtensionShowsConfigurationUI` (bool set to YES).

Also, when I go to Project > Targets > *any of the targets* > Capabilities > Autofill Credential Provider, I get a `Add the Autofill Credential Provider feature to your app ID` error message. I went already into my apple's developer account and the app ID is properly set for that feature...

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: If you didn't let Xcode update the provisioning profile for you, then you will need to download the updated provisioning profile from the developer portal and add it to Xcode.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

From @Paulw11 in the comments

> If you didn't let Xcode update the provisioning profile for you, then you will need to download the updated provisioning profile from the developer portal and add it to Xcode.